# Get attribute from multiple attribute sets

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, product-attribute, attribute-set

I'm trying to select all products with an attribute called `uitgelicht_product` set to `Ja`. It's not the first time that I'm doing this and it usually goes well, but this is situation is a bit different, because I have 2 different attribute sets. The attribute occurs in both attribute sets: `Default` and `Test`.

I'm able to retrieve the products with `uitgelicht_product` set to `Ja` in the `Default` set, but I also want the products from the attribute set `Test`. I tried using this to see if I can get it only from `Test`:

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','39');
```

But this doesn't return anything, while 39 is the attribute ID of `Test`. Changing 39 to 4 (the id of the Default set) works fine and returns the product using the attribute set Default with `uitgelicht_product` set to `Ja`.

How do I get the products with `uitgelicht_product` set to `Ja` in both the `Test` as the `Default` attribute set?

This is the entire code I'm using to retrieve the products:

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');

$yesOpID = null;
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'uitgelicht_product');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
    foreach ($options as $e) {
        if ($e['label'] == 'Ja'):
            $yesOpID = $e['value'];
        endif;
    }
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('uitgelicht_product', $yesOpID);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', '39');
$products->addStoreFilter();
$products->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
$products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$products->getSelect()->limit(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make your attribute uitgelicht_product with yes/no and then add
in both attribute set and set some product yes. and please use below code.

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('uitgelicht_product','1');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','9');
//here 9 is my attribute set
print_r($products->getData());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
    $attribute_set_id = array('4','39');
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
                ->addAttributeToFilter('uitgelicht_product','Ja')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',array('in' => $attribute_set_id));

    print_r($products->getData());

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't return anything. It returned:
`Array ( )`

Comment: check now i had changed code

Comment: Sorry, it still shows the same result. Could it be that it has something to do with a setting?